# Wikimedia API - How can I get all resolutions of an image

Tags: wikipedia-api

I want to copy images from a wikipedia page.
When I do it manually, I click on the picture, and then select the resolution that fits my need (width as close to 400).
Now, I am using the Wikimedia API to get the images.
But they give me only one resolution.
I saw a similiar question in Stackoverflow, but the answer was to use the iiurlwidth=400
I used it, and it does not do it (it is probably only for vector pictutres).

Comment: Could you include an example of the URL that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found that the answer to use the iiurlwidth=400 was correct, but the reply is not in the "url" item, but in the "thumburl" item,which is in the right width.